# RadioButton click on another form

Tags: c#, click, radio-button

We have a legacy program with a GUI that we want to use under control of a C# program to compute some values.  We can successfully enter values in the numerical input controls, press the compute button, and read the produced answers from text display boxes.

But **we can't seem to control a pair of radio buttons .**

Calling CheckRadioButton() returns a code of success, but the control does not change state.
Sending a message of BM_CLICK does not change the state.
Attempts at sending WM_LBUTTONDOWN and WM_LBUTTONUP events haven't changed the state.

Has anyone been successful at "remote control" of radio buttons?

Portions of code to illustrate what we are doing:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="SendMessage")]
public static extern int SendMessageStr(int hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, string lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, uint Msg, long wParam, long lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="FindWindow", SetLastError=true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="CheckRadioButton")]
public static extern bool CheckRadioButton(IntPtr hwnd, int firstID, int lastID, int checkedID);

static IntPtr GetControlById(IntPtr parentHwnd, int controlId) {
  IntPtr child = new IntPtr(0);
  child = GetWindow(parentHwnd, GetWindow_Cmd.GW_CHILD);
  while (GetWindowLong(child.ToInt32(), GWL_ID) != controlId) {
    child = GetWindow(child, GetWindow_Cmd.GW_HWNDNEXT);
    if (child == IntPtr.Zero) return IntPtr.Zero;
  }
  return child;
}

// find the handle of the parent window
IntPtr ParenthWnd = new IntPtr(0);    
ParenthWnd = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "Legacy Window Title");

// set "N" to 10
IntPtr hwndN = GetControlById(ParenthWnd, 17);
SendMessageStr(hwndN.ToInt32(), WM_SETTEXT, 0, "10");

// press "compute" button (seems to need to be pressed twice(?))
int hwndButton = GetControlById(ParenthWnd, 6).ToInt32();
SendMessage(hwndButton, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);
SendMessage(hwndButton, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);

// following code runs succesfully, but doesn't toggle the radio buttons
bool result = CheckRadioButton(ParenthWnd, 12, 13, 12);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the [BM_SETCHECK message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775989%28VS.85%29.aspx).  Be sure to use a tool like Spy++ to see the messages.

Comment: Thanks, this does work.  It did not work initially, but I found I had a bad handle for the RadioButton.  I did not realize that the Frame surrounding the RadioButtons was actually their parent.

Answer (score 0):

in this case i used another message BM_SETSTATE

```
SendMessage((IntPtr)hWnd, Win32Api.BM_SETSTATE, (IntPtr)newState, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Comment: I have tried this command:
SendMessage(hwndRBtn, BM_SETSTATE, 1, 0);
with no success.